# Using Google Geocoding with Python

Tags: python-3.x, geocoding

I was just curious if anyone has had some success installing and importing the Geocoding module into Python.  I believe I have successfully done this, but then the results of my queries are atypical.

For instance, whenever I enter an address with just a street name and number, it gives me a Query Error like this:

> geopy.geocoders.googlev3.GQueryError: The geocode was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the geocode was passed a non-existent address or a latlng in a remote location.

However, if I include a city and/or state in the address, the query will run and return the place as only the city and state, and will basically disregard the street number and street name and will give me the lat and lng of the center of that city.
Example:

```
place,(lat,lng)= g.geocode("4224 Evans to Locks Road Augusta Georgia")
```

I just was wondering if there was perhaps a problem in my installation or something that is preventing the `geocode` from working.  I honestly have no idea how this kind of problem occurs and am very new to Geocoding.  I have moderate experience working with Python however. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try putting a comma between the street and city. If that doesn't help, post your code as I can't make heads from tails of it from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Geopy, however if you use [Geocoder](https://github.com/DenisCarriere/geocoder) on GitHub/PyPi you should be able to accomplish everything you need, lots of documentation to help you get started.

Here's how you would use it following your example:

```
>>> import geocoder
>>> g = geocoder.google("4224 Evans to Locks Road Augusta Georgia")
>>> g.latlng
(33.5411157, -82.11359039999999)
>>> g.json
...
```

How to install:

```
pip install geocoder
```